# Updating a JSON file generated from Database to be manipulated with javascript

Tags: php, json, fetch

I'm building a web app that is written purely in javascript, however I am storing values in a mySQL database. To access the data in the database I am calling it in php using MySQLi etc.

I'm generating the JSON file OK, by doing the following:

```
$showData = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{    
   array_push($showData, $row);           
}

$json_data = json_encode($showData);
file_put_contents('showData.json', $json_data);
```

This is generating the JSON fine, however this is run everytime someone visits the page. So whenever someone hits the page, it's going to rewrite the JSON. This works great as it's constantly updating the JSON for whenever there are changes and it ensures the showData.json file is always up to date.

Here is the javascript fetch that is getting the data from the JSON file:

```
fetch("showData.json")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(function(showData){
    getShowData(showData);
});
```

Again this works fine, however it doesn't seem the most efficient way to do this, writing to a file each time someone hits the page seems "wrong". What are the alternatives? Is there a better way to get JSON data without reading from a JSON file?

Comment: Are you against calling the php directly, to have it simply echo out the json, instead of saving to a file?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading from the JSON file, run a PHP script that generates the JSON from the database:

```
fetch("getData.php")
```

The `getData.php` would be exactly like your first script, but instead of writing the JSON to a file it ends with:

```
echo json_encode($showData);
```

Comment: There's no reason to do this at the application layer.  This problem is best solved with HTTP caching.

Comment: @Brad How does that solve the problem of rewriting the JSON file all the time?

Comment: The web server caches the response from PHP and serves that to users.  PHP never even has to execute to handle the data.

Comment: What if the database contents have changed?

Comment: You either flush the cache explicitly, and/or you use the ETag header to indicate that there is new data.

Comment: @Brad Isn't that done internally and transparently by `fetch()`?

Comment: Thanks Barmar, works perfectly and seems a lot cleaner. Funnily enough it seems slower than doing the write to JSON file but this may just be as I'd already cached the JSON etc. Just one thing, how come the $showData is echoed rather than returned?

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```
$showData = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
array_push($showData, $row);
}
$json_data = json_encode($showData);
?>

<script>
<?php echo $json_data; ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The best thing to do is to keep your logic but simply echo out the JSON and enable caching at the HTTP server level.

There are a lot of options for cache control, so start here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Your HTTP server can cache the response from PHP and serve it directly to clients.  Clients can cache that response without even having to touch your server.  You won't have to modify your code other than to add the appropriate response headers.  Using `ETag`, you can also invalidate a cache when content changes.

Comment: The issue he's raising is not with fetching the data, it's with the need for a script that rewrites the file every time someone goes to the website.

Comment: @Barmar I'm aware.  I clarified my wording... let me know if it still doesn't make sense.